# Let E = ${x + \frac{4}{x}: x > 0}$. Prove or disprove that E is a bounded set.

Tags: real-analysis

I know that it is a bounded below set and the infimum is 4, but I'm unsure of going about how to prove that it is indeed bounded. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Formatting tip:  use `$\{$` to get $\{$.  What happens to $x+\dfrac4x$ as $x\to\infty$?

Comment: You think it's bounded... Hmm... What happens when $x\rightarrow +\infty$? Moreover, the infimum is 4.

Comment: Try plotting the function. Can you see an upper bound?

Answer (score 1):

Consider Positive Values for x alone for now,

AM-GM

$x + \frac 4x \geq 2 \sqrt {x \frac 4x}$

$f(x) \geq 4$

It is Easy to see that it is a monotonically increasing function beyond x = 2 by differentiating,

Thus it suffices to show that Limit at Infinity Is not Infinity, Easy to see that It is,

Noe generalize this to -ve side as it is an odd function. This gives you the Range $(-\infty,-2] \ U \ [2,\infty]$ and thus it's unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

Hint #1: If you want to investigate intuitively whether or not it is bounded, try evaluating $x + \frac{4}{x}$ for values of $x$ that get larger and larger, such as $x=10$, $x=100$, $x=1000$, $x=100000$, and so on.

Hint #2: Perhaps, if someone tells you "This number $B>0$ is an upper bound", you can figure out rigorously whether or not they are telling the truth by attempting to solve the inequality $x + \frac{4}{x} > B$.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I can indeed prove that it has no upper bound, but I must prove using the formal definition of a lower bound, (Let A be a subset of the reals, A not empty, we'll say L is a lower bound for A f for all a in A, L is less than or equal to a.

Comment: @fancyfawn28971:  bounded means bounded above and below.  If you only want to prove it is bounded below, you should say that.